# The recurrence interval for an Add-on trigger must be at least one hour

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

I wrote a google app script add on which has an installable trigger to run cron job. It is published as a private add on which can only be used by defined group members.

Initially I put the trigger to run every 5 minutes, but started seeing error "The recurrence interval for an Add-on trigger must be at least one hour" which made me change the trigger to run every 2 hours.

However, am still getting above error when testing as a user from private testing group.

Anyone has faced/solved it?

thank you

Comment: You probably just need to re-deploy the add-on at a new version.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, i did it a few times with no luck :(.

Comment: In add-ons, "Time-driven triggers cannot run more frequently than once per hour." ([Source](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers#restrictions_2)) If you've confirmed that there are no other time-triggers (you could try [deleting all](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deleteTrigger(Trigger))), then you may want to try re-creating and seeing if the error persists.

Comment: @DimuDesigns - Actually I had to unpublish and republish to make it work (publishing the new version doesn't work).

Now I get  another error "This add-on has created too many time-based triggers in this document for this Google user account."

Actually am calling 2 triggers under a called function, I couldn't find any documentation which says I can add only one trigger in an add-on, but i will try removing one of them and see if it works. thank you for your help.

Comment: @Diego - thank you, its not the case as I have restricted the function to only create triggers if they aren't any already.